# How to add/link react project in HTML page?

Tags: reactjs, web, web-deployment

To describe the situation,
I have my whole portfolio website built in PHP. let's call this `www.example.com` and my work page called `www.example.com/work.php`

I have linked my JS counter app in work page as `website/work/counter1.html` using a href tag and it works.

but how do I link my react counter app as I did with counter app? a href to `"counter2/public/index.html"` just shows blank as I guess it needs some sort of npm deployment?

The app works on localhost if I run `npm start` beforehand in proj2 directory and link it to `localhost:3000/work/counter2`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are describing how you run the app on localhost. That isn't available to the public.  Where have you deployed this react app?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was using heroku just until this morning, I had added node.js buildpack but deployment used to fail.

Comment: Most react projects can be deployed to static hosting.  Why not just put it on the same server as the rest of your website?

Comment: No the whole site was on heroku as I had implemented login system in php long ago and I am looking at AWS at the moment.

Comment: Try to build your react-app. It gives you static .js and .html files. Add them to the your portfolio project. And gives link to this static html page. After that, if you can't see the page, please open browser console. There should be error message in there. We will take action according to that later.